# OpenSSL callback/user pointer

Tags: c++, openssl

Does OpenSSL have a concept of a callback/user pointer that you can set and use to "pass" member function pointers via forwarding through a static function pointer?

Comment: Usually, yes. But you need to be more specific what you are asking about. For example, `SSL_CTX` family has `SSL_CTX_set_verify` to set callback function and `SSL_CTX_set_app_data` to set passed user pointer.

Comment: Oh okay thx, can i somehow get the SSL struct when i only have the SSL_CTX struct and vice versa?

Comment: I am using mqtt_cpp library https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp which uses boost asio, and i only see a boost::asio::ssl::context